# How to put www in front of a wordpress site url in htaccess?

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a wordpress site accessed like `http://example.com/`

but my client wants to have it accessed like `http://www.example.com/`

I am finding this code as a solution

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**But I am getting an error of redirect loop**

Could you please advice me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can the site currently be accessed on `www.domain.com` at all? Without the rewriterule? If it can't, you may have to fiddle with the central server configuration first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing `http://` from your `www` forcing rule. Also important is to have your www rule before other WP rules:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Also **don't forget to change WP permalinks to have `www` in Site and Home URLs**

Comment: If it's not a caching issue, try commenting out with # the WP rules (at bottom) and seeing if the www rule works. Then reverse the commenting-out and see if the WP rule works. One or the other must have a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You have an easy way to do this inside of wordpress:

Go to your wordpress dashboard and:

1) Select Settings
2) Select option General,
3) Add to your WordPress Address (URL) the www part
4) Add to your Site Address (URL) the www part

And done!